# What does complexification mean in complex analysis, .e.g., in residue calculus,

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I've learned complexification formally in a graduate linear algebra class.  But what does the word mean in the setting of complex analysis?

If I consider a real integral on the positive half line, and then look at the integral on a semi-circle (to use the Residue Theorem), then the variable changes from x to z, with differential changing from dx to dz.  Is this considered "complexifying the integral"?

Thanks,

Comment: This seems like a reasonable interpretation to me. It's not a term that I've used exactly, but I do write down $z$ for $x$ if I'm about to write a complex contour integral.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks @mixedmath.  Yea, I'm just wondering if there's a formal *structure* to it, like the word has in linear algebra ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say so, but I guess that's a point of view.

You don't go from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$, to replace $x$ by $z$. You **start** at $\Bbb C$. You do complex integrals over curves, and you parametrize curves. The real line seen inside $\Bbb C$ is just one more curve, among a lot of them, which happen that you can parametrize by $\gamma(t) = t$, with $t$ in some interval, or whatever. Since $t$ is a dummy variable, you might as well write $\gamma(x) = x$, and then you get ${\rm d}z = {\rm d}x$.

I would say that can you see real integrals as particular cases of complex line integrals (with complex functions), over the curve $\gamma(x) = x$ (or some part of it).

Comment: Hi @IvoTerek, yes, I see what you're saying.  But I have seen the term used in some notes for complex analysis, particularly for the topic of residue calculus, so I just wanted to get some clarity on it.  Perhaps the word is just loosely used in complex analysis ...when we can look at real and imaginary parts of a complex integral - even though the end goal is to compute a real integral, which should yield a real number.  So, in this sense, I think it is in fact going from R to C, and then back to R.  (In linear algebra, complexification has a formal definition, but the idea is the same:

Comment: complexify a real operator, then transfer the results back to the real operator...)

Comment: I think the terminology is sometimes used in the spirit of "let's complexify this integral and see if we can compute it!".  In that sense, I believe 'complexify' usually means to regard the integral as taking place over the real axis $\textit{in}$ $\mathbb{C}$, exactly as Ivo says. The thing to beware of is that for this to make sense, your original real integrand should have a complex extension (usually you will want an analytic extension in order to make use of residue calculus).

Comment: ok got it, thanks @john!

Comment: thanks so much, @ivoterek!  :-)